# How to get Tkinter to input text and submit with button

Tags: authentication, tkinter

Hi I was wondering if anybody could help me submit code from the text fields to the login fields and then br.submit(name="wp-submit") with the login button

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
        import resources.lib.mechanize as mechanize
        mechanize

# Start Browser
br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())

# User-Agent (Firefox)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
br.open('http://razetheworld.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Frazetheworld.com')

br.select_form(name="loginform")
br['log'] = 'entryWidget_U must enter here'
br['pwd'] = 'entryWidget_P must enter here'
br.submit(name="wp-submit")

print br.geturl()

def displayText():
    """ Display the Entry text value. """

    global entryWidget_U
    global entryWidget_P

    if entryWidget_U.get().strip() == "":
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Enter a Username")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Text value =" + entryWidget_U.get().strip())

    if entryWidget_P.get().strip() == "":
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Enter a Password")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Text value =" + entryWidget_P.get().strip()) 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()

    root.title("Tkinter Entry Widget")
    root["padx"] = 40
    root["pady"] = 20       

    # Create a text frame to hold the text Label and the Entry widget
    textFrame_U = Frame(root)
    textFrame_P = Frame(root)

    #Create a Label in textFrame
    entryLabel = Label(textFrame_U)
    entryLabel["text"] = "Enter Username:"
    entryLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

    entryLabel = Label(textFrame_P)
    entryLabel["text"] = "Enter Password:"
    entryLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

    # Create an Entry Widget in textFrame
    entryWidget_U = Entry(textFrame_U)
    entryWidget_U["width"] = 50
    entryWidget_U.pack(side=LEFT)

    entryWidget_P = Entry(textFrame_P)
    entryWidget_P["width"] = 50
    entryWidget_P.pack(side=LEFT)

    textFrame_U.pack()
    textFrame_P.pack()

    button = Button(root, text="Login", command=#Run br.submit(name="wp-submit"))
    button.pack() 

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Nervermind I figured it out

```
# File name: tkinterEntryWidget.py
# Author: S.Prasanna

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
        import resources.lib.mechanize as mechanize
        mechanize

def displayText():
    """ Display the Entry text value. """

    global entryWidget_U
    global entryWidget_P

    # Start Browser
    br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())

    # User-Agent (Firefox)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
    br.open('http://razetheworld.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Frazetheworld.com')

    br.select_form(name="loginform")
    br['log'] = entryWidget_U.get().strip()
    br['pwd'] = entryWidget_P.get().strip()
    submit = br.submit(name="wp-submit")

    print br.geturl()

    if entryWidget_U.get().strip() == "":
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Enter a Username")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Text value =" + entryWidget_U.get().strip())

    if entryWidget_P.get().strip() == "":
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Enter a Password")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Tkinter Entry Widget", "Text value =" +
entryWidget_P.get().strip()) 

    if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()

    root.title("Tkinter Entry Widget")
    root["padx"] = 40
    root["pady"] = 20       

    # Create a text frame to hold the text Label and the Entry widget
    textFrame_U = Frame(root)
    textFrame_P = Frame(root)

    #Create a Label in textFrame
    entryLabel = Label(textFrame_U)
    entryLabel["text"] = "Enter Username:"
    entryLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

    entryLabel = Label(textFrame_P)
    entryLabel["text"] = "Enter Password:"
    entryLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

    # Create an Entry Widget in textFrame
    entryWidget_U = Entry(textFrame_U)
    entryWidget_U["width"] = 50
    entryWidget_U.pack(side=LEFT)

    entryWidget_P = Entry(textFrame_P)
    entryWidget_P["width"] = 50
    entryWidget_P.pack(side=LEFT)

    textFrame_U.pack()
    textFrame_P.pack()

    button = Button(root, text="Login", command=displayText)
    button.pack() 

    root.mainloop()
```